# Using a delegated constructor with try-with-resources idiom within another constructor

Tags: java

I have class `Foo` that has two ways of being constructed:

```
public Foo(Bar bar)

public Foo(Baz baz)
```

It's possible to get a `Baz` from a `Bar` with a try with resources idiom like

```
try (Baz baz = bar.expensiveFunction()){
    // code here
}
```

What I want to do is in the `Foo(Bar bar)` constructor, essentially write

```
public Foo(Bar bar)
{
    try (Baz baz = bar.expensiveFunction()){
        this(baz);
    }
}
```

but this is not allowed as `this(b)` is not on the first line. Does anyone know how I can achieve this in Java? Of course, I could use an `initialise` function, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Only by delegating to another method. Like `handleBaz(Baz baz)`, in both constructors.

Comment: @MystyxMac: An issue with that approach though is that then any fields set by the constructor can't be `final`. Might not be an issue though: perhaps the OP will confirm.

Comment: I do have some final methods. Your answer could work but I wait until there are other answers.

Comment: I assume that it is your intention that `baz` is closed ... irrespective of the success of the 2 constructors.  Correct?  Either way, I don't think there is any way to do that ... without defining a 3rd constructor.

Comment: @StephenC sorry but I don't know what you mean by closed.

Comment: You know what the try-with-resources does with the resource .... don't you?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bathsheba's approach is better.  But I think there is a way that works with just constructors ... in some circumstances.

If the `Foo` class extends `Object`, you can do this:

```
public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this(bar.expensiveFunction(), true);
}

public Foo(Baz baz) {
    this(baz, false);
}

private Foo(Baz baz, boolean close) {
    super();
    try {
       // initialize
    } finally {
        if (close) {
            baz.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If `new Foo(someBar)` throws an OOME in the initial allocation of the `Foo` object, that will occur before the call to `expensiveFunction()` occurs, so there will be no `Baz` to be closed.

But if `Foo` extends some other class, then the `super()` call in `Foo(Baz, boolean)` *could* throw an exception ... which *cannot* be captured in `Foo`.  And if you can't capture the exception, then you can't close the `Baz`.

Comment: Much prefer this to my answer; it symmetrises the calling site. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative, which avoids an `initialize` function (which would mean, for example, that fields couldn't be `final`), is to refactor the more "expensive" function into a `static`:

```
public static Foo makeFoo(Bar bar){
    try (Baz baz = bar.expensiveFunction()){
        return new Foo(baz);
    }
}
```

which ought to afford minimal pollution at calling sites.